# No baseThemes inside 'material-ui' npm package

Tags: reactjs, themes, material-design, material-ui

I decided to try http://www.material-ui.com/ with darkBaseTheme.

But when I installed package via

```
npm i --save material-ui
```

I got the package without styles/baseTheme folder. That's why I can't import this theme with code from an [example](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes):

```
...
import darkBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme';
...
```

Can someone please tell me what did I do wrong? I'm a little bit stuck here

Comment: I just tried with a blank app created with create-react-app. I installed material-ui the same way you did, which brings version 0.20.0 to the project, and the import worked fine. Which version of material-ui do you have in you package.json ?

Comment: "material-ui": "^0.20.0"

Comment: That's weird, seems we have the same setup. Did you try to uninstall and reinstall the dependency ? And then, check npm logs.

Comment: If you're just starting out with material-ui, [you should use v1](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui#should-i-start-with-v1-beta).

Comment: Thank you guys! I find that in the latest version there is no baseThemes.

Comment: @uhthska You don't have the latest version. You have 0.20.0 and the latest is 1.0.0-beta.35. Are you sure you've provided the correct `npm` install instruction and `package.json` version?

Comment: in my packaje.json now:

"material-ui": "next"

Comment: anyway in this version no getMuiTheme also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in the latest v1-beta baseThemes not included at all.

[Here is the repository with the last commit at that moment](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/88df41baea698944ce1915e925694ef425910766/src/styles)